# What is the control group in neutrino detection?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, particle-detectors

Assuming we can't block neutrinos, and most of them pass through the earth, how do we know that the change in the neutrino detector is not just happened randomly? Is the detection of neutrinos more frequent when earth is closer to the sun, or are we just always seeing the same amount of neutrinos in the detectors because we have no way to block them?

Comment: The real answer to your wuestion doesn't depend on it, but since you asked: yes, [the variation in neutrino flux due to the Earth's orbital eccentricity is detectable](https://indico.cern.ch/event/818781/contributions/3672491/attachments/1964504/3266227/NuPhys19Slides_susana.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer - one can detect what direction neutrinos come from. Neutrino detectors don't just count neutrino collisions.

Neutrinos either hit something in the detector or they themselves are converted into electrons. The resulting particle moves faster than the speed of light in the medium and Cherenkov radiation is emitted. From the direction the Cherenkov radiation is emitted, you can get the direction the charged particle was moving. This is correlated with the direction the neutrino was going.

[This paper](https://journals-aps-org.libproxy.berkeley.edu/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.211101) says the incoming neutrino direction is "blurred" by 25 degrees because the charged particle doesn't have the same momentum as the incoming neutrino. But if you collect lots of events, you will be able to figure out where your neutrinos are coming from.

The paper is talking about getting enough statistics to tell where *within the sun* neutrinos come from. But if you just read the introduction it's a prety good description of how we know where neutrinos come from.

Edit: also some neutrino detectors detect neutrinos from various nearby nuclear reactors. And in some cases they also do measurements when said reactors are off.